# How to solve npm error “npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE”

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I'm trying to learn webpack following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzdEpgONurw,the video using webpack 4,but I use webpack 5,while I down load webpack-dev-server and npm start,it did not work,I think it is not the issue of version,because I am not totally follow the video,this is my debug log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v12.19.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle tut@1.0.0~prestart: tut@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle tut@1.0.0~start: tut@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle tut@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle tut@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Walter\Desktop\tut\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Walter\AppData\Roaming\ActiveState\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo IDE 12\;C:\Users\Walter\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Walter\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle tut@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Walter\Desktop\tut
10 silly lifecycle tut@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack-dev-server --open' ]
11 silly lifecycle tut@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle tut@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: tut@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --open`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid tut@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Walter\Desktop\tut
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.19.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error tut@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --open`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the tut@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tut",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack": "^5.1.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "http-server": "^0.12.3"
  }
}
```

Here is webpack.config.js

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.html$/i,
          loader: 'html-loader',
          options:{minimize:true}
        },
      ],
    },
    devServer:{
        contentBase:'./dist',
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template:"./src/index.html",
        filename:"./index.html"
    }),
   ]
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your `start` script in package.json to `webpack serve` like so:

```js
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack serve"
  }
```

For enabling HMR, try updating your `devServer` object in `webpack.config.js` like so:

```js
devServer: {
   contentBase: './dist',
   hot: true, // <---- add this line
},
```

Comment: my giant mentor,yes,it works smooth.in the dependencies,I install  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",and why can not start with"webpack-dev-server --open" from webpack official doc link:https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-webpack-dev-server?

Comment: new issue,my mentor,while I use your snippet,[WDS] Live Reloading  not working,it means:it can be compile but can not be auto-reload.

Comment: try adding `hot:true` to your devServer object in `webpack.config.js`